# My Angular 6 application cannot consume Express API

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I created a simple nodejs project as a backend server. When I tried to consume "http://localhost:3000/users" in my Angular 6 project, I always encountered http response errors. But if I use the json server as the backend server to provide the same API, it works. I tested both with my browser and Postman, and I am pretty sure the nodejs Express server and the json server provide exact same content. Who can help me fix this issue? Thanks very much!

my nodejs app.js code,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.route('/users').get((req, res) => {
  res.send(
    [
      {
          "id": "5b03d4dd1a193d0ab08b1af8",
          "username": "bwteksuper",
          "level": 3,
          "is_active": true,
          "created_date": "2018-05-22T08:29:17.200000Z"
      },
      {   
          "id": "5b03d4f81a193d0ab08b1af9",
          "username": "jade",
          "level": 2,
          "is_active": true,
          "created_date": "2018-05-22T08:29:44.492000Z"
      }
    ]
  );
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

my json server db.json,

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "5b03d4dd1a193d0ab08b1af8",
            "username": "bwteksuper",
            "level": 3,
            "is_active": true,
            "created_date": "2018-05-22T08:29:17.200000Z"
        },
        {   
            "id": "5b03d4f81a193d0ab08b1af9",
            "username": "jade",
            "level": 2,
            "is_active": true,
            "created_date": "2018-05-22T08:29:44.492000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

my Angular code,

```
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]>{
    return this.http.get<User[]>('http://localhost:3000/users');
  }
}

export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  users: User[];

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService
      .getUsers()
      .subscribe(data => {this.users = data;});
  }
}
```

Http response error,

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown         Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
core.js:1598
error:ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, …}
headers:HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message:"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
name:"HttpErrorResponse"
ok:false
status:0
statusText:"Unknown Error"
url:null
__proto__:HttpResponseBase {constructor: }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

> EXPRESS

```
 var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

    // Hello.
    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.send('Hello');
    })

    // User page route.
    router.get('/users', function (req, res) {
      res.send(/* USER JSON HERE */);
    })

app.use('/api', router);
```

> ANGULAR

```
 getUsers(): Observable<User[]>{
    return this.http.get<User[]>('api/users') // Without http://3000
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I think you may be on the right way. If doing so, I need to add something like parent url, but I don't know how to. Do you have any idea? Anyway, after I enable CORS in my node.js server project, it works.

Comment: what do you mean with "I need to add something like parent url"

Answer (score 0):

Just to enable CORS in the nodejs project can fix this issue.